# Conditional query of sort key in DynamoDB not working?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am building a trivial API using API Gateway through to DynamoDB.  I am trying to do a conditional query against a sort key and I keep getting the message "Query key conditional not supported."  However, everything I've read in the documents said this should indeed work.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
{
    "TableName": "testTable",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "requestTimeEpoch > :since",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":since": {
            #if($input.params('since') != "")
                "S": "$input.params('since')"
            #else
                "S": "1"
            #end
        }
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that someone had this issue when using a Number, so I tried switching it to a String instead.  Either way, shouldn't this work?

(requestTimeEpoch is the sort/range key for the hash key)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the sort key on its own. Data is only sorted within its partition. So you need to specify a partition key (this has to be an equals operator) on your query.

If you don't want to use your partition key, you need to switch to a scan operation. A scan doesn't require any key conditions.

EDIT: So with a partition (hash) key it might be something like

```
{
    "TableName": "testTable",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "YourHash = :hash and requestTimeEpoch > :since",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":since": {
            #if($input.params('since') != "")
                "S": "$input.params('since')"
            #else
                "S": "1"
            #end
        ":hash" : {S: 'yourHashId'}
        }
    }
}
```

and a scan

```
var params = {
    TableName: "testTable",
    FilterExpression: "#since > :time",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#since": "time",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":time": 2017,
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense then.  I was not quite understanding how it was stored internally, even though I read the documents.  Unfortunately, that means I can't really use this directly from the API Gateway like I was hoping.  I'll need to use a Lambda function so I can use a hash key of the day or month, which I can't get directly using only the Mapping... so close, yet so far!